# Replace a word with plus-sign

Tags: javascript, regex

When I'm trying to remove a certain word from an input, it removes the first time that specific word occurs in the input *(also if the word is a part of another word)*.

But what I want to do, is only remove the word I wrote where it is the full word, and not if it is a part of another one.

This is my code:

**HTML:**

```
<input value="c++ c+ c" />
```

**JavaScript:**

```
$input = $('input');
$word = "c+";

$input.val( $input.val().replace($word, "") );
```

The output of this will be:

```
+ c+ c // Removed the "c+" part of the "c++" word
```

..but  want it to be:

```
c++ c // Removed "c+"
```

I have tried to use a regex `/\bc+\b/g` but that seems to remove every occurrences of that word.
But if I want to remove a word without a `+`-sign, the above code works fine.
I know that when using `+` and other signs, you should escape it, but that I've also tried with no luck.

```
$input.val( $input.val().replace(/\bc\+/, "") );
// Output: + c+ c // Removed the "c+" part of the "c++" word
```

Here it is replacing the first part of "c++" like in the first example.

[Live Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tz2s06un/3/)

Anyone who knows how I fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work;

```
/\bc\+(?=\s|$)/g
```

This will catch plus characters if they are followed by a space or at the end of the string.

Fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/xLpschsw/)

Comment: Thank you so much. That did the work! :D

Instead of ending with a "\\b" in my escape function, I changed it to "(?=\\s|$)".

Answer (score 1):

This allows you to construct a `RegExp` from your input, and replace matches that are between spaces, or at the beginning or end of the string.

```js
RegExp.escape = function(s) {
  return s.replace(/[-\/\\^$*+?.()|[\]{}]/g, '\\$&');
};

var value = 'c+ c++ c+ c+c c+ c',
  $word = RegExp.escape('c+'),
  regex = new RegExp('(?:^|\\s+)' + $word + '(?:\\s+|$)', 'g');

$('input').val(value);
$('input').val($('input').val().replace(regex, ' '));
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input></input>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with

```
str.replace(/\bc\+(?=\s|$)/g, "");
```

Note the `/g` at the end - that means replacing all occurences.

EDIT: As mentioned in keune's answer you should check that `c+` is followed by a space (`\s`) or it is end of a string (`$`)

Comment: It still removes the first part of the "c++" word

Comment: Ah, yes, you're right. I think I'll just point to @keune's answer